# Tkinter buttons only work once

Tags: python, tkinter

In this MainFrame class I have 4 buttons that each import a class in a new window when clicked (except for Update). I can click each one of the buttons once, but if I ever try and click on a button for a second time, no new window will pop-up and nothing will happen at all. Why does each button only work once?

```
  from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tm
import Users
import re
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('game nebula.db')
c = db.cursor()


class MainFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master
        self.mainUI()

    def mainUI(self):

        self.master.title("Games Nebula")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        frame1 = Frame(self)
        frame1.pack(fill=X)
        frame2 = Frame(self)
        frame2.pack(fill=X)
        frame3 = Frame(self)
        frame3.pack(fill=X)

        self.label_1 = Label(frame1, text="Welcome to Games Nebula!", fg='green', relief='groove', width='40')
        self.label_1.pack(side=TOP, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.searchbtn = Button(frame2, text="Browse Games", fg='green', command = self._search_btn_clicked)
        self.searchbtn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=25, pady=10)
        self.addbtn = Button(frame2, text="Add games", fg='green', command=self._addbtn_btn_clicked)
        self.addbtn.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=25, pady=10)
        self.updatebtn = Button(frame3, text="Update", fg='green', command=self._update_btn_clicked)
        self.updatebtn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=40, pady=10)
        self.deletebtn = Button(frame3, text="Delete Games", fg='green', command=self._delete_btn_clicked)
        self.deletebtn.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=25, pady=10)


    def _search_btn_clicked(self):
        print("Searching")
        import GameSearch


    def _addbtn_btn_clicked(self):
         import Add

    def _update_btn_clicked(self):
        print("Updating")

    def _delete_btn_clicked(self):
        import Delete


root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x200+300+300")
lf = MainFrame(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Because modules are only imported once: when the module has been imported, python will refer to it and not import it again.

It is bad practice, **so don't do it**, but if you want to force a re-import, you can do like this:

```
import importlib

importlib.reload(module_name)  # attention: the module must have been 
                               #            imported first for this to work
```

I fail to see why you want to import (and re-import) modules at the click of a button.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want to do is repeatedly run some code in each module.  AS RB explained, repeatedly importing a module does not do that.  What you should do is to defined functions and classes in the module that you can call after importing.  If nothing else, wrap everything in a function called main and use, for instance, `command=Add.main` when you define the Add button.  (First put `import Add` at the top of the program.)

Testing a module is much easier when importing it merely defines objects and binds then to names, without having side-effects like long-running computations and opening windows.